# Google Voice in iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-voice

I can find this [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8) but I cannot find it in iPad. How can I use Google Voice in iPad?

> **Perhaps related**
>
> 1. [Can the iPad 2 be used for everyday telephony?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/can-the-ipad-2-be-used-for-everyday-telephony)
> 2. [Is the 3G network used by the iPad the same as the 4G network used by the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43120/is-the-3g-network-used-by-the-ipad-the-same-as-the-4g-network-used-by-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to give [GV Connect](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gv-connect-call-sms-client/id347835665?mt=8) a try or [Talkatone](http://www.talkatone.com/).

Both work on iPad with instructions [here](http://gigaom.com/apple/your-ipads-a-telephone-with-google-voice/) and [here](http://geekwhat.com/2011/06/22/how-to-use-google-voice-ipad-2-phone/).

Comment: ...tested both in Android and iPad. GV Connect is not supported in Android. Talkatone is supported in Android and iOS. Both uses Google Voice. UI is clearer with GV Connect but poor integration to contacts. Talkatone sync painlessly with contacts from services such as Google Account contacts and Facebook contacts. So chose Talkatone. Minus side with them: the Google Voice number apparently supported only in States, sadly, so needs to use traditional carriers. Thank you for suggestion -- now having almost real extra phones with 3G connected devices.

Comment: I use Talkatone but I have used an odd thing: some posts get to my iPad while some posts get only to my Desktop, any idea why?